# Mixed processing of data from Memcached and Database in a Social networking platform

Tags: java, mysql, performance, caching, memcached

I am working on a `J2EE/MySQL` based Social networking platform which allows users to Write Blogs, Ask Questions, Wiki Pages, Putting Challenges, Putting Custom Quizes etc.

Since this kind of platform generates lots of data, there is need to make sure that site performs well.

I have decided to use `Memcached` for completely caching data at Blog, Wiki, Questions levels from relational DB.
This will make sure that when ever user hits these pages, data will be delivered from `memcached`. Hence DB load will reduce.

DB will be hit only when there is a new record added and in some rare cases.

Further to this, following is where it gets complicated:

- System also has a permission system.
- Each user has different kind of permission on the data depending on user has created it or not and some other rules.
- Caching Blog, Wiki, Questions level data with permission applied will need replicating data by session-and-user-id as key. This will need too much memory.
- I have decided to fetch Blog, Wiki, Questions level data from `Memcache` and permission level data from DB and then apply permissions to data coming from `memcached` at run-time.

I am worried that applying permissions to such a huge data at run time might take longer processing time and may overshadow advantage given by `Memcached` cluster implementation.

Please let me know your inputs.

Comment: To summarize, you will query the DB to check permission before serving memcached content. And so are worried about the possible performance issues. Or have I totally misunderstood you?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Here I can check Memcached for data and DB for permissions parallely. But I am worried about performance issues which might come while mixing.